# How to prevent browser to follow href='#'

Tags: javascript, html

Hello recently I'm facing a new problem. I used a custom html code in the middle section of my website. After implement the html my website automatically go to that section after loading. I think this is the culprit:3

```
<div class="results" id="results">
   <a class="domain" href="#" id="domain">helloworld.com</a>
</div>
```

Here there is an hash tag that force browser to go to this particular section. That is to say I used "javascript:void(0)" instead of # but nothing improved.
My question is how can I push browser to say header and not to follow that result id.

Comment: As far as I know, if your address contains `#blaa` and your page have some element with same id e.g. `blaa` than it'll definitely scrolls there.

Comment: No my home page look like "https://stackoverflow.com/" this. This is why I couldn't understand why this is happening.

Comment: If the url is `...yourpage.html#results` it will load scrolled to the element with ID "results".  `href='#'` will link to the same page but at the top (i.e. no in-page anchor.). It's not at all clear from your question what you're trying to accomplish (what does "how can I push browser to say header" mean?)

Comment: Hey @DanielBeck yes. I'm trying it without using javascript. Is it possible?

Comment: You're trying _what_?

Answer (score 1):

Simple use javascript
It will changes hash in url from anything to your required `header`

Make sure your header has the id attribute `header`.

```
window.location.hash = "header";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the browser to follow a link (with an assigned **href**) with some simple JS code:

```
document.getElementById("domain").onclick(e => e.preventDefault());
```

Where **e** is the Click event object.

Although a **javascript:void(0)** on the **href** property should do the trick too.

You should probably also set the link's **rel** property to **nofollow**, like this:

```
<a class="domain" href="#" id="domain" rel="nofollow">helloworld.com</a>
```